# Defining an artifact name explicitly when publishing with Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, ivy

I'm trying to publish to the local repository but to set the artifact name explicitly.
For example, say the org is "quick.fox" and the module is "core" with version being 1.1.

What I get is:

`<repo>/quick.fox/core/1.1/core-1.1.jar`

What I'd like it to be:

`<repo>/quick.fox/core/1.1/prefix-core.jar`

a basic sample code would be:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      group = "quick.fox"
      artifactId = "core"
      version = "1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

How would I do that? I'm using Gradle 6.5.1, and I am open to using either the maven or ivy publish plugins.